# How to replace particular patterns of text with HTML tags on front-end using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

There is a field in the CMS that does not allow HTML, but now we have to do some complex CSS styling to change the layout.

My idea is to replace some particular patterns of text with HTML tags.

For example, to change:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <figcaption>###2022-10-01###Opening Ceremony</figcaption>
  ...
  <figcaption>###2022-10-02###Welcoming Speech</figcaption>
  ...
  <figcaption>###2022-10-03###Race Day</figcaption>
</div>
```

into:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <figcaption><span class="date">2022-10-01</span>Opening Ceremony</figcaption>
  ...
  <figcaption><span class="date">2022-10-02</span>Welcoming Speech</figcaption>
  ...
  <figcaption><span class="date">2022-10-03</span>Race Day</figcaption>
</div>
```

Note: `###2022-10-02###Welcoming Speech` is what I can put into the field.
So it is not a must to be `###`. It can be other text, symbols, or patterns.

Shall we use `htmlContent.replace`? And I have to target all matched patterns on the web page. I am not sure how to do it correctly.

Trying on CodePen: https://codepen.io/pen/qBYXxbm

Comment: What is the question? How to replace the text on front end using javascript?

Comment: @asyncawait yes, correct. thanks! let me try to modify the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Details are commented in example**

```js
// Collect all <figcaption> into a NodeList
document.querySelectorAll("figcaption")
  // For each <figcaption>...
  .forEach(cap => {
    // ...split it's text at "###" into an array
    const text = cap.textContent.split('###')
      // ...filter any empty parts of the array
      .filter(t => t);
    //console.log(text);
    /*
    Render the template literal within the <figcaption>
    interpolate the content of array text
    */
    cap.innerHTML = `<span class="date">${text[0]}</span> ${text[1]}`;
  });
```

```css
section,
figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.date {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://s.abcnews.com/images/International/olympics-fireworks4-gty-ml-220204_1643987789890_hpEmbed_3x2_992.jpg" width="240">
    <figcaption>###2022-10-01###Opening Ceremony</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://gupshups.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Welcome-speech-for-the-seminar.jpg" width="240">
    <figcaption>###2022-10-02###Welcoming Speech</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://cdn.quotesgram.com/img/70/24/616754473-2c33e6276057e5c799641af64e446ccb.jpg" width="240">
    <figcaption>###2022-10-03###Race Day</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression replacement.

```
htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/###(.*?)###/g, '<span class="date">$1</span>');
```

`(.*?)` is a capture group that captures everything between the pair of `###`, and `$1` in the replacement string copies that this captured.

```js
let htmlContent = `<figcaption>###2022-10-01###Opening Ceremony</figcaption>
...
<figcaption>###2022-10-02###Welcoming Speech</figcaption>
...
<figcaption>###2022-10-03###Race Day</figcaption>`;

htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/###(.*?)###/g, '<span class="date">$1</span>');
console.log(htmlContent);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am trying on https://codepen.io/pen/qBYXxbm but not working yet, I probably miss something.

Comment: You're not setting `htmlContent` or displaying the result anywhere.

Comment: Thanks~ I am new to javascript, sorry... I have to target all matched patterns dynamically on the web page, so instead of putting everything for `let`, I am trying `let htmlContent = document.querySelector("figcaption");` ... but obviously not working yet

Comment: `let htmlContent = document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML;` where `.container` is the element that contains all of the `figcaption` elements.

Comment: no luck: https://codepen.io/pen/qBYXxbm .....  shall it be like this? `let htmlContent = document.querySelector(".wrap").innerHTML; htmlContent = htmlContent.replace....`